# Memory leak, how to detect what is causing it using MS Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I've been adapting [this code](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/) (the c++ version) to my needs, which involves running over a very long video sequence. After a few hundred frames, the program crashes due to memory issues. If i check the memory used by the process, it is using more than 1.6 GB RAM. Checking memory usage (in a very dumb way using windows task manager..) i've noticed that every frame uses pretty much the same amount of extra memory.

I've been told that using MS Visual Studio (the IDE i'm currently using) i should be able to see, at a certain point, which variables are using more memory, in order to find which one is causing the memory leak and to fix it, but i couldn't find anything about it in the IDE.

If possibile, i'd like not to use tools like Valgrind and solve the problem using Visual Studio. If not..well, i'll think about that when i'll get there :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `valgrind`  ?

Comment: I'd have to port the interaction with the file system that my program does to linux..i should probably start doing that by using `boost` anyway, but detecting the memory leak with ms visual studio would save me some time..

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Can you show some code? The small example on the web page you linked calls `malloc` with no `free`, so if you just copied that, you'll certainly have some leaks.

Comment: Have a look at [DrMemory](http://www.drmemory.org/). It is super easy to use and I found it invaluable for the task you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found that Microsoft's UMDH ("user-mode dump heap") tool has saved me time and again.  You can find detailed information [on this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343/en-us).  To simplify using it, I'm including here a toy program that has everything you'll need to integrate UMDH into your own program.

The toy program allocates 1000 chars without releasing the memory, and includes the UMDH scaffolding you need.  Here's the source code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

bool SpawnProcessWin32 (char *command, DWORD &returnCode)
{
    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    bool ret = false;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    // Start the child process.
    if( !CreateProcessA (NULL,      // No module name (use command line).
                        command,    // Command line.
                        NULL,       // Process handle not inheritable.
                        NULL,       // Thread handle not inheritable.
                        FALSE,      // Set handle inheritance to FALSE.
                        0,          // No creation flags.
                        NULL,       // Use parent's environment block.
                        NULL,       // Use parent's starting directory.
                        &si,        // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure.
                        &pi )       // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure.
        )
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError ();
        printf ("error = %d\n", error);
        goto exit;
    }

    // Wait until child process exits.
    WaitForSingleObject (pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Check exit code
    DWORD dwExitCode = 0;

    GetExitCodeProcess (pi.hProcess, &dwExitCode);

    if(dwExitCode == STILL_ACTIVE)    
    {
        // Process did not terminate -> force it
        TerminateProcess (pi.hProcess, 0); // Zero is the exit code in this example
        returnCode = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        returnCode = dwExitCode;
    }

    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );

    ret = true;

exit:
    return ret;
}

void foo ()
{
    char *buffer = new char [1000];
}

void main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined (USE_UMDH)
    char strCommand [1024];
    bool spawnRet;
    DWORD retCode;

    // For debugging purposes, take initial snapshot of memory
    sprintf (strCommand, "C:\\junk\\umdh.exe -p:%ld -f:c:\\junk\\findleak.dump.1", GetCurrentProcessId());
    spawnRet = SpawnProcessWin32 (strCommand, retCode);
    assert (spawnRet);
#endif

    foo ();        // This function will leak memory on purpose

#if defined (USE_UMDH)

    // For debugging purposes, take terminal snapshot of memory
    sprintf (strCommand, "C:\\junk\\umdh.exe -p:%ld -f:c:\\junk\\findleak.dump.2", GetCurrentProcessId());
    spawnRet = SpawnProcessWin32 (strCommand, retCode);
    assert (spawnRet);

    // Now take a diff of the two dumps
    sprintf (strCommand, "C:\\junk\\umdh.exe -d c:\\junk\\findleak.dump.1 c:\\junk\\findleak.dump.2 -f:c:\\junk\\findleak.dump.diff", GetCurrentProcessId());
    spawnRet = SpawnProcessWin32 (strCommand, retCode);
    assert (spawnRet);
#endif
}
```

Here are the points to take note of:

1. The UMDH utility is included with the Standalone Debugging Tools for Windows.  Download and install the Debugging Tools (for example, [see this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513)).
2. The umdh.exe utility is launched three times in the program: once to create a memory snapshot before starting the app, once to create a memory snapshot when the app is finished, and final time to create a snapshot diff.
3. I wrote a handy function called SpawnProcessWin32 to launch the umdh.exe program each time.
4. I inserted "#if defined (USE_UMDH)" in the code to enable/disable the UMDH code.  In projects I write, I like to leave the UMDH scaffolding code in place for future use.  If I suspect a memory leak I just define USE_UMDH and everything is set to debug.
5. Modify the command passed to SpawnProcessWin32() to suit your needs.  In my example I placed umdh.exe in my c:\junk folder, and had umdh.exe place its output in the same folder.

When you've run your app, just check the diff file produced by the last call to umdh.exe.  Here's what I get with the above toy program:

```
// Debug library initialized ...
DBGHELP: DemoUmdh - private symbols & lines 
        c:\junk\TestProjects\DemoUmdh\Debug\DemoUmdh.pdb
DBGHELP: ntdll - export symbols
DBGHELP: KERNEL32 - export symbols
DBGHELP: KERNELBASE - export symbols
DBGHELP: MSVCR90D - export symbols
//                                                                          
// Each log entry has the following syntax:                                 
//                                                                          
// + BYTES_DELTA (NEW_BYTES - OLD_BYTES) NEW_COUNT allocs BackTrace TRACEID 
// + COUNT_DELTA (NEW_COUNT - OLD_COUNT) BackTrace TRACEID allocations      
//     ... stack trace ...                                                  
//                                                                          
// where:                                                                   
//                                                                          
//     BYTES_DELTA - increase in bytes between before and after log         
//     NEW_BYTES - bytes in after log                                       
//     OLD_BYTES - bytes in before log                                      
//     COUNT_DELTA - increase in allocations between before and after log   
//     NEW_COUNT - number of allocations in after log                       
//     OLD_COUNT - number of allocations in before log                      
//     TRACEID - decimal index of the stack trace in the trace database     
//         (can be used to search for allocation instances in the original  
//         UMDH logs).                                                      
//                                                                          


+    1036 (   1036 -      0)      1 allocs  BackTrace2
+       1 (      1 -      0)    BackTrace2  allocations

    ntdll!RtlLogStackBackTrace+7
    ntdll!RtlCreateUserThread+15BE5
    ntdll!RtlInitializeCriticalSectionEx+129
    MSVCR90D!malloc_base+EE
    MSVCR90D!malloc_dbg+306
    MSVCR90D!malloc_dbg+BF
    MSVCR90D!malloc_dbg+6C
    MSVCR90D!malloc+1B
    MSVCR90D!operator new+11
    DemoUmdh!foo+28 (c:\junk\testprojects\demoumdh\main.cpp, 64)
    DemoUmdh!main+A8 (c:\junk\testprojects\demoumdh\main.cpp, 85)
    DemoUmdh!__tmainCRTStartup+1A8 (f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c, 586)
    DemoUmdh!mainCRTStartup+F (f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\crtexe.c, 403)
    KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+E
    ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+85
    ntdll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain+58


Total increase ==   1036 requested +     28 overhead =   1064
```

The diff reports a total increase of some 1036 bytes after the app finished, indicating a leak.  The calling stack trace shows the exact location of the leak:

```
DemoUmdh!foo+28 (c:\junk\testprojects\demoumdh\main.cpp, 64)
```

This corresponds to the true culprit:

`char *buffer = new char [1000];`
.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It took me some time to figure out exactly how it worked but it did the job, thanks! Next time it all go faster, hoping that i won't need it again though :)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is possible to use CRT to debug to track down memory leaks, I would recommend [**Visual Leak Detector**](http://vld.codeplex.com/): nice, straight-forward and integrates into Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012.

### Pros:

- Integrated
- Simple usage (one include makes it functional)

### Cons:

- Can be really slow on large block leaks as it will display the whole leaked block

PS: apologies for how long this post went un-spell-checked: I blame the manufacturers of my finingerses firmware for not releasing an update in time! ;-)

If only it worked like this then I would have perfect spelling!
[image: If only it worked like this then I would have perfect spelling!]

Comment: hmmm again with silent down-votes, I don't mind any down-vote, but please leave a constructive criticism so I can learn from it, otherwise you are effectively just swearing at me rather than saying something useful.

Answer (score 0):

For very basical and hand made memory leak search the leak detection build in the MS Runtime can be used.

[Microsoft artikel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx)

A dump is used and breakpoints are set later on. This works well for algorithms/workflows that are reproducible.

- Run first time
- dump not free mem at a given point
- Set breakpoint to referencing mem pointer

Maybe this could help.